# What is this widget property from the StatefulWidget flutter

Tags: android, inheritance, flutter, frameworks

I sometimes see something like:
`widget.title` or `widget.(anything)` in flutter; like this example in the *Text widget child* of an `AppBar` Widget:

```
class MyApp extends StatefulWidget{
    // some declarations here
    @override
    _MyApp createState() => _MyApp();
}

class _MyApp extends State<MyApp>{
   // some declaration here
    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context){

        return MaterialApp(
            home: Scaffold(
               appBar: AppBar(child: Text(widget.title),),
            ),
        );
    }
}
```

what *is* this actually?

`widget.title`
I mean, what is the `widget` referencing? what is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `MyApp` class extends StatefulWidget, which means this widget stores mutable state. When the MyApp widget is first inserted into the tree, the framework calls the `createState()` function to create a fresh instance of `_MyAppState` to associate with that location in the tree. (Notice that subclasses of State are typically named with leading underscores to indicate that they are private implementation details.) When this widget’s parent rebuilds, the parent creates a new instance of `MyApp`, but the framework reuses the `_MyAppState` instance that is already in the tree rather than calling createState again.

To access the properties of the current `MyApp`, the `_MyAppState` can use its `widget property`. If the parent rebuilds and creates a new `MyApp`, the `_MyAppState` rebuilds with the new widget value. If you wish to be notified when the widget property changes, override the `didUpdateWidget()` function, which is passed as oldWidget to let you compare the old widget with the current widget.

Now as Per Docs: **widget property**

> This property is initialized by the framework before calling
>   initState. If the parent updates this location in the tree to a new
>   widget with the same runtimeType and Widget.key as the current
>   configuration, the framework will update this property to refer to the
>   new widget and then call didUpdateWidget, passing the old
>   configuration as an argument.

[reference link](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/State/widget.html)

Answer (score 1):

Long answer short

You have extended the [`State`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/State-class.html) class.
The `State` class has a `readonly` property called [`widget`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/State/widget.html). Which is what you are referencing to.

Answer (score 0):

The **widget** property is a part of the State class, which inherits it in the _YourWidgetState class. This _YourWidgetState class is a subclass of the State class.

When you examine the State class reference, you will find:

```
abstract class State<T extends StatefulWidget> with Diagnosticable {
    get widget => _widget!;
    T? _widget;
}
```

In this context, T represents the type parameter of the State class, which, in this case, is your custom widget class. Consequently, the **widget** property within the State class refers to an instance of your custom widget class.

Let's consider the example of the BiggerText widget:

```
class BiggerText extends StatefulWidget {
   final String text;

   const BiggerText({Key? key, required this.text}) : super(key: key);

   @override
    State<BiggerText> createState() => _BiggerTextState();
}

class _BiggerTextState extends State<BiggerText> {
   double _textSize = 16.0;

   @override
   Widget build(BuildContext context) {
     return Column(
       mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
       children: <Widget>[
         Text(**widget.text**, style: TextStyle(fontSize: _textSize)),
       ],
     );
   }
}
```

based on the example above

```
class _BiggerTextState extends State<BiggerText>
```

The code signifies that _BiggerTextState inherits the **widget** property from the State class, thanks to being a subclass of the State class.

Within the State class, the **widget** property represents an instance of the generic type T, which, in this case, corresponds to the BiggerText class. As a result, the **widget** property in this context is an instance of the BiggerText class itself.

So, when you use, for instance, **widget**.text, you're accessing a property of the BiggerText class.